How to pass a query result to TextField using a function in PowerShell and ConsoleGuiTools Module?
I'm trying to query mysql and populate a TextField using Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools. So far I Wrote this piece of Code below. When I tested on Powershell the function Get-Sistema returns the apropriete value, but it doesn't populate the TextField2. Testing that field with other function which returns a single string it works, so i belive it has something to do with the type of return on PowerShell:
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools 
$module = (Get-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools -List).ModuleBase
Add-Type -Path (Join-path $module Terminal.Gui.dll)
[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.3.0\MySql.Data.dll")


function Get-Sistema {
    param([string]$Id)
    $Mysqlhost= "localhost"
    $Mysqluser= "user"
    $Mysqlpass= "pw"
    $Mysqldatabase= "db"
    $Connection = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]@{ConnectionString="server=$Mysqlhost;uid=$Mysqluser;pwd=$Mysqlpass;database=$Mysqldatabase"}
    $Connection.Open()
    $sql = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    $sql.Connection = $Connection

    $sql.CommandText = "SELECT nome_sistema FROM sga_sistemas WHERE ID = $Id" 
    $myreader = $sql.ExecuteReader()
    while($myreader.Read()){ $myreader.GetString(0) }
    $myreader.Close()
}


[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Init()
$Window = [Terminal.Gui.Window]::new()
$Window.Title = "SGA"

$Lb1 = [Terminal.Gui.Label]::New()
$Lb1.Text = "OBJETO:"
$Lb1.Width = 10
$Lb1.Height = 1
$Lb1.Y = 0
$Window.Add($Lb1)

$Field1 = [Terminal.Gui.Textfield]::New()
$Field1.Width = 20
$Field1.X = [Terminal.Gui.Pos]::Right($Lb1)
$Field1.Y = 0
$Window.Add($Field1)

$Field2 = [Terminal.Gui.TextField]::New()
$Field2.Width = 20
$Field2.Y = 1
$Window.Add($Field2)


$Button = [Terminal.Gui.Button]::New()
$Button.Text = "_Consultar"
$Button.add_Clicked({
        $Field2.Text = Get-Sistema -Id [string]$Field1.Text
})
$Button.X = [Terminal.Gui.Pos]::Right($Field1) + 1
$Button.Y = 0
$Window.Add($Button)


[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Top.Add($Window)
[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Run()
[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Shutdown() 



Shouldn't that be $Button.add_Click({..}) instead of $Button.add_Clicked({..}) ?

If i just set $Field2.Text = "Test", after clicking the $Button it displays 'Test' string, so the name of the method is ok.
